# How do I get my skspritenodes to appear in the same spot on different sized screens?

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I made a game using sprite kit but when I run it on ipod 5 or iphone 5 it works but not on the 4 or 4s. Is there any way to fix this or will it just not work on smaller screens?

Comment: set your nodes positions dynamically

Comment: Use percentage of the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

They did a great job explaining the initial planning phase to cater for universal app.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/49695/sprite-kit-tutorial-making-a-universal-app-part-1

The gist is to set a screen boundary according iPhone 5 (since the ratio is the odd one) and take set the node to the screen ratio (with Scale Mode set to Fill).

e.g.:

```
self.scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)*9.5/10,self.frame.size.height*8.8/10);

self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
```